# how to enable subdomains on forge

Tags: subdomain, laravel-forge

I created a new site with Forge and gave it this domain: abcd.test.com

Forge created the site and created the folder abcd.test.com where my files are stored.

When I try to access the abcd.test.com I get an error: Server not found.

What do I need to do? Do I need to do something at my domain provider to enable subdomains?

Comment: This is exactly what I have. Did you ever solve this issue? I want a single subdomain with a separate source (and contents) installed through Laravel Forge. But I'm not sure how to setup the DNS settings in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your DNS (domain provider) settings probably needs to be changed.

You're probably missing the CNAME row.

`*        CNAME         @`

[image]

You're using Namecheap as a domain provider;
    [Subdomain docs Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-a-url-redirect-for-a-domain)

Comment: this is what I have right now: http://i.imgur.com/FNz00yA.png What should I put for CNAME? can you give me an example for subdomain?

Comment: shouldn't I add A record subdomain.domain.com that points to the servers ip address?

Comment: Add - Type: CNAME, Host: *, Value: @  and add Type: A, Host: @, Value: ip-address.   Your domain provider will check your forge name (imageshare.code4fun.io) and will link it to the correct domain. You don't need to add an A record with your domain name.

Comment: I changed A record from www to @ as you said and proceded to add CNAME host: *, value: @ and got this error: http://i.imgur.com/EbeevF7.png Error occured: INVALID_ADDR : '@' should not be an IP/ URL for CNAME record.(host name: *)

Comment: I'd suggest following the namecheap docs (which you are using) : [Namecheap docs](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-a-url-redirect-for-a-domain)

Comment: I cannot fill in `@` as the CNAME value of host `*`
BTW, should the CNAME host be `*.mydomain.com` ?

Comment: @mesqueeb yes, with some domain providers you don't have to add the domain, and with some you have to.